# AstroNvim in diff mode: navigating to next difference

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, vimdiff, astronvim

In plain old (n)vimdiff, one can jump to the next/previous difference using <kbd>[c</kbd> or <kbd>]c</kbd> respectively. (says `:help diff` documentation, at least)

Not so much in my AstroNvim; running `nvim -d -R old.txt new.txt`, after typing <kbd>[</kbd>, there's no <kbd>c</kbd> option (and pressing <kbd>c</kbd> just exits the menu):

[image: Screenshot of my terminal emulator showing neovim running the AstroNvim frontend, showing the key selection choice after pressing \, not encompassing a c option]

So, how does one navigate nvimdiff from within AstroNvim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option indeed (I believe because `]c` is a standard functionality and that are no added mapping has been introduced) but the command do work (at least for me).

Comment: they don't work for me, as said :(

Comment: Your screenshot shows two files that look very similar.  Could you provide one with two files with clear differences may be some additions?

Comment: sure, give me a minute

Comment: fantastic! Now it works! (just made a 100 lines file, `for i in {1..100}; do echo $i >> text.original; done`, deleted and duplicated a few lines and added some text in a line, and it now does work) So, it might be a file size problem? interesting, but not subject of my question!

Comment: I'm happy to hear your problem is moving. For me it also work on some small files (30 lines). Maybe you need to type the two keys fast enough (check the value of the `timeout` option with `:set timeout?` I have configured it two 2 sec `:set timeout=2000`)

Comment: no, I've tried different cadences; maybe the diffing process times out on the ~ 5MB file.